# proof if $P(\alpha$)=0 and $\alpha^i\neq 1$ then $P$ is irreducible

Tags: finite-fields, minimal-polynomials, primitive-roots

In [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory)) state the following :"a primitive polynomial is the minimal polynomial of a primitive element of the finite extension field . In other words, a polynomial a primitive polynomial if its degree is m and it has a root $\alpha$ such that $\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha ^{2},\alpha ^{3},\dots ,\alpha ^{p^{m}-2}\} $  is the entire field".

i don't get how the two definitions are equivalent.

My second question: let say I have a polynomial $P$ of degree $m$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ and $\alpha$ is a root of $P$ in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, and if $\alpha$, $\alpha^{2}$, $\alpha ^{3}$, ... ,$\alpha ^{p^{m}-2}$ are all different from $1$, does it imply that $P$ is irreducible?

Comment: yes thank you @TorstenSchoeneberg i copy and past it and forget to remove 0 and 1

Comment: The number of invertible elements in the degree $m$ extension of $\Bbb F_q$ is $q^m-1$, not $p^m-1$ (usually in such a context $q$ is taken to be a power of a prime $p$). Should we assume you meant $q^m$ rather than $p^m$ in the exponents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, the degree of the minimal polynomial of any element in a field extension is the degree of the smallest sub-extension that contains it; for a primitive element$~\alpha$ of a degree $m$ extension there are no strict such sub-extensions, so this degree is$~m$. Then any monic polynomial of degree$~m$ having$~\alpha$ as root must be that minimal polynomial, hence irreducible.

As for the second question (if we exclude the obvious counterexample $\alpha=0$), if you have a nonzero root$~\alpha$ of a degree$~m$ polynomial over $\Bbb F_q$, you know that its minimal polynomial has degree at most$~m$, so $\alpha$ lives in a multiplicative group of order at most $q^m-1$ (of the field $\Bbb F_q[\alpha]$). If that number is indeed the multiplicative order of$~\alpha$ as your hypothesis implies (so $\alpha$ generates said multiplicative group) then all inequalities above must be equalities, an in particular your original polynomial is the minimal polynomial of$~\alpha$, hence irreducible.

Comment: the square of a polynomial of degree $m$ have degree $2m$ so my statement will became:  $\alpha^i \neq 1$ for $ 1 \leq i \leq q^{{2m}-2}$ and do not holds

Comment: I see; adapted my answer